# ColdFusion count the amount without using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, count, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to count the amount without using `SQL count()` code 
Is there a way to extract the results including the number amount over ColdFusion?

```
Select test
From ......
Where .....


<Cfif not test.RecordCount>
No records found
</Cfif>
<cfoutput query="test">#amount#</cfoutput>


It should display like this
TEST      CountOutput 
TEST A:   22
TEST B:   32
TEST B:    1
TEST C:   23
```

Comment: What are those numbers, record counts from a database?  I'm not sure I understand your question.  Maybe just initialize a variable and then add to that variable as you loop over the query(ies).

Comment: yes, record counts from a database.i want to avoid  `select count()` in the `SQL` and display it directly over ColdFusion.

Comment: Just have a number being incremented inside the loop, that will keep a record count

Comment: thx. @TheMegatronMan, may can you share an example?

Comment: As you have shown in your example, `{query name}.RecordCount` will give you the count for a particular query. If you are wanting a total from multiple queries just add them together; `query1.RecordCount + query2.RecordCount + query3.RecordCount`

Comment: @Miguel-F, thank you but is not that what i'm looking for.

Comment: @Stef - Do you mean "count" or "sum" (ie total)? They're not the same thing. It'll be easier to help if you could please post a) an example what your current code outputs and b) an example of what it *should* look like instead? **Edit** Also, why can't you use SQL for this?  Answering those questions will better help us to assist you.

Comment: @Ageax, i want to show the output + total. 
i have 200 rows e.g. cars, apple ect.
The problem which i have is that is don't now yet the pieces so i wanted to count it first and then display it as 

Cars: 10 Pieces. 
Apple: 20 Pieces. 

Can you give me please en example how do you would it? thx.

Comment: @Stef - You don't need to know what the elements are to perform a count. Just do a `select column, count(*) AS someAlias from table group by column`. Unless there's a valid reason you can't use a count, sql is the simplest way to aggregate. https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php

Comment: @Ageax, THX!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

(From comments ...)

Why can't you use SQL for this? Unless there's a valid reason you can't use COUNT, it's by far the simplest way to aggregate. You don't need to know the specific values in the database table in order to perform a [COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm). Just do:

```
SELECT column, count(*) AS someAlias 
FROM   tableName 
GROUP BY column
```

Yes, it is possible to do the same in ColdFusion code, but again unless there's a specific reason to do so, it's more efficient to use SQL.

Comment: Also, since your example uses `#amount#`, if you're not familiar with aggregate functions, keep in mind COUNT (number of distinct items) is different than `SUM` (total of the values).

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset data = {} />
<cfset names = {} />

<cfloop query="test">
     <cfif not structKeyExists(data, test.name)>
         <cfset data[test.name] = 0 />
         <!--- if you need to preserve original case of name --->
         <cfset names[test.name] = test.name />
     </cfif>
     <cfset data[test.name] += 1 />
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop collection="#data#" item="key">
        #names[key]#: #data[key]#<br />
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the total count without using SQL, Use

> QUERYVARIABLE.RECORDCOUNT

Based on the condition used in the SQL query it will give you the count.

FOR Example,

```
<cfquery name="test">
SELECT * FROM database WHERE name=testA
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#test.RECORDCOUNT#" />
```

Use this within a function, call it and store the return value in a stack or an array.

Answer (score 0):

I *strongly* recommend you use a SQL Count(). I cannot imagine why you would want to do it inside a CFLoop or CFOutput, but it is possible if you use the Group attribute, and count each row that way.

Did you know that after you execute CFQuery against your SQL server to get all those detail records, you can run a "query of queries" summarize the SQL data. This article seems to explain it:
https://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_query_of_queries.cfm